# C# Create array without incremental indexes

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to see if there is a way to have an array where it's index's are not 0,1,2,3 etc.

I have a 3d array {x,y,z}.

y and z would be increasing from 0 to a normal value.

However, x could take values say 1,4,5,9,10. I would want to access the element by its true x value rather than map it to another value (1=>0, 4=>1, 5=>2 etc).

Anyone have any ideas if this is possible without wasting memory (just creating an array with length of the largest x value).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you use Point3D class? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.point3d.aspx based on your description, it could represent what you want.

Comment: would i be able to use it in the same way as an array. Have many x y z co-ordinates and assign some sort of variable type to that co-ordinate. @Andrea

Comment: `Dictionary`? E.g. `Dictionary<(int x, int y, int z), string> sample = ...` then `sample.Add((2, 3, 4), "Foo");`